# Local Notification Not Firing With Background Fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

Can someone please take a look at the following code and tell me why the local notification isn't firing. Im running the app in XCode and using the debug option to simulate a background fetch but the local notification doesn't fire.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
 {
     NSLog(@"performFetchWithCompletionHandler");


UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if (localNotif) {
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Update demo text!";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"OK";
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.fireDate = nil;

    NSLog(@"Local Notification");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}

//Perform some operation
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you query the user to allow push?

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0) {
      UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
      [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }
```

Comment: Ahh I don't that might be it.

Comment: Perfect, that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking device version, use below code that checks **RespondToSelector:**

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```