# Send local notifications about new JSON data from closed app? | Swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView that is being populated using JSON data. At this time anytime there is an update to the JSON the user needs to pull down to refresh the tableView and the new data will load.

Is it possible to have the data refresh in the background when the app is exited or completely not even open on the user's phone and send the user a local notification saying there is new data?

How can this be done? I am more focused on local notifications.

**Example of how I am currently getting my app to read JSON:**

```
private func fetchJSON() {

guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example.php"),
    let value = name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
    else { return }

var request = URLRequest(url: url)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
    guard let data = data else { return }

    do {
        self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([structure].self,from:data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
              }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    }.resume()

}
```

An example of how the api looks like from the address **example.com/example/example.php** is the following:

```
[{"person":"Jackson","number":"1928192",
"position":"driver"},{"person":"Jeff","number":"293829","position":"driver"}]
```

Comment: How and from where do you receive that JSON data? How do you know, that there is an update?

Comment: The JSON data is created in PHP and looks at a mySQL db

Comment: Is it possible to make the app background refresh every few minutes and see if info changed?

Comment: Well, yeah, but how do you receive it from server? I suppose, you're working with standard client-server architecture, which means, on iOS part you're sending a request to get data from server on page viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method. That means, there's no simple way for server to say you, there's an update. Refreshing every X minutes is a very rough approach, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I posted an example of how my app is currently populating the tableView

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :- Store json in UserDefault or in CoreData

if you are using UserDefault i personally perfer PropertyListEncoder&Decoder.

Step 2 :- Enable Background Capability

Step 3 :- implement local notification code in you app.

Comment: Is there an example you can show or Git project you would recommend?

Comment: For Background Fetch : - https://gist.github.com/RameshRM/8ca0a1be512520a5240e and also https://stackoverflow.com/q/36356310/9697632 take look.

Comment: if you provide api then i can also implement this functionality.

Comment: I posted an example of what the api looks like